# Spring boot 1.4.1 embedded tomcat 8 - Logs are buffered for 30 sec

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Tomcat's logs (`access_log`) are buffered for 30 seconds before they are flushed. How can I remove this delay? I want to have real-time logs in my `access_log`. In Spring boot 1.5, I have

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=true;
```

in `application.properties`, which I think does exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the change log](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b60150b05ea19f2db52773fa809e9900b28a2df0), `server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered` has been introduced since v1.5.0.RC1.
So if you want to use it, you may have to upgrade or apply the change to Spring Boot 1.4.1.

See also:
[Allow setting of `buffered` field on `AccessLogValve` property via `server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered` #7456](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7456)